# Automatic build of platform-specific executables on git push?

Tags: git, build, continuous-integration

Similar to how, on push, a continuous integration service like Travis CI will build your project, does a service exist to automatically build your git project? Where several executables would be created, for Windows, Linux, macOS, 32-/64-bit, etc.

If not, would a chron-job be appropriate? Or, some kind of installer that itself is static but downloads the repo and builds on install time?

Comment: You can usually set up continuous integration severs (e.g. TeamCity) to build whatever you want. For example you can have a configuration per each target platform you listed, all of which are triggered to build upon a git push and/or every night.

Comment: Thanks @CoryKramer. I don't think I was clear enough in the original question, but I'm looking not for something that tests if it *can* be built, but to actually build an executable which can then be uploaded to a web server for user download. I looked over TeamCity and it doesn't seem to have this capability. Any ideas?